# How to change character background opacity?

Tags: swift

I am using Swift 5.

My first test was to change the background of my label and use the opacity. It is ok, but now I would like to try to change the character's background opacity only and not the full background label.

For this, I have no idea where to start.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Use `NSAttributedString` to change the color of only one character instead of the full string, ie the color setting can be done per character? Or is it because you set a background color in your Label, and you want one letter to have the "color" of the view behing the label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this, change AlphaComponent value according to you preference:

```
let text = "your label text"
    
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
    
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```swift
sender.alpha = 0.5
```